# How to find similarity between two vectors?

Tags: python, vector, pytorch, similarity

I have two embedding vectors A1 and B1, of size 32 (it could be 64, and so on).

```
A = torch.rand(32)
A1 = torch.unsqueeze(A, dim = 1)
A1

B = torch.rand(32)
B1 = torch.unsqueeze(B, dim = 1)
B1
```

Now, I want to be able to find how similar are they, based on every say 4, 8, 16 elements. So that the output will look like a vector of say 4 (or 8 ... and so on) elements.

```
ExampleOutput = [.4, .5, .6, .7] # as the window is 8 (from 32 sized vector)
```

Meaning that the similarity will be computed over a window. I know one way could be using torch histogram.

1. Any idea how can I compute this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Similarity" isn't well defined. If you mean cosine similarity then you could use something like `torch.cosine_similarity(A.reshape(-1, 8), B.reshape(-1, 8), dim=1)`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit ambiguous. What do you mean by similarity? For instance, if you consider two 2-element vectors, you could compute L1,L0 (Manhattan distance) ,L2 (MSE) ,L... L_infinity, cosine similarity, etc. There are a number of similarity metrics for vectors.

Secondly, how do you intend to "pool" the vectors? You could compute the similarity metric and then take the min/max/average over each window. You could take the min/max/average over each window and then compute similarity. You could come up with some other in-between approach.

In short, there are many ways to do this, and the method you choose should be informed by the structure of your inputs and the context of your problem which are outside of the question's scope and provided details.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. What I wanted,... for example if the vectors are two waves (32 elements). And the output will show another wave in smaller number of elements (16 elements). I have come across TS-SS. That I could not figure out how to get similarity as 16 elements, out of 32 sized vectors.

Comment: Ok, so in this case you expect the vectors to have some element-to-element structure, which means you'll need to use a different class of similarity metrics, e.g. frequency response methods such as Fourier analyses might be suitable. Think carefully about what you want. If two waves are identical in frequency and amplitude but out of phase, are they similar? What about identical in amplitude and phase, or frequency and phase but not amplitude?

Comment: In general you need to think carefully about how you define "similarity". For instance in say the MNIST dataset (pictures of handwritten digits from 0 to 9) two pictures of the same number may have individual pixel values that are quite dissimilar. So the similarity method must account for 2D spatial relationships between elements. Very interesting to get into the weeds on what we mean by similarity in an abstract sense

Comment: But if we constrain ourselves to thinking about merely the downsampling of each vector (and then define a similarity metric later for the downsampled vectors) you can easily accomplish that by interpolation (see `pytorch.nn.functional.interpolate`) https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#interpolate

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in comparing 2 vectors (velocities).
I currently use the dot product of the 2 vectors divided by square of the length of the largest vector.  This has the advantage that as well the direction as the magnitude are taken into account to measure 'similarity'.
The formula gives you a number between -1 and +1. You get +1 if the vectors are identical.  The result is negative if the directions differ more than 180 degrees.  (My own code uses a value > 0.7 to decide if velocities are similar.)

e.g. for 2D vectors:

```
similarity = dotproduct(a, b) / max(norm(a), norm(b))^2
        or
similarity = (ax*bx + ay*by) / max(ax*ax+ay*ay, bx*bx+by*by)
```